# Remove Roomba's questions from the delete tools

Tags: discussion, feature-request, deleted-questions, vote-to-delete, 10k-tools

I am refering to [this tools page](https://stackoverflow.com/tools) available at 10K Rep.

I think it's a good idea if we only show questions that really deserve our delete votes and hide the ones that will get automatically deleted. It would be more efficient to spend our votes instead of simply making the auto-delete process faster.

I usually find myself dealing with new asked questions waiting for a last delete vote. I am obliged to cast a vote<sup>1</sup> because if I don't do, the list won't refresh to see other questions (and there is no option to show more). On the other hand, there are questions that really need my delete votes but not shown in the list.

As a side note, it would be good if we can improve the tool by adding some filter (by tag, by dates, by close reason, etc). It's easier for me to judge an *opinion based* question rather than a `python` duplicate questions so I would better hide the latter one.

Worth to note that an actual filter is already made for the "close" tab. Would be good to replicate for the "delete" tab:

> [image]

---

A last suggestion around deletion: I would like to get a warning when deleting questions saying

> Are you sure you want to delete this question? It will get automatically deleted in X days.

I don't remember all the Roomba rules so if I have such warning I can avoid wasting some delete votes.

<sub>1: Of course, it's not a blind vote simply to see more questions. There is simply no urgency in deleting the question sooner.</sub>

<sup>PS: this is not a discussion about when to delete and when not or if it's good to delete or not. I simply want an improvement to the existing tool.</sup>

Comment: It would also be great if that tool only shows recent delete votes for questions I could cast a delete as well (when the post deserves it). Prior 20k we have to wait for 2 days after the question has been closed.

Comment: @Tom The page already indicates which posts you can vote on based on your reputation. Items you can't delete vote on are greyed out and in a smaller font. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/aavp9.png as an example.

Comment: @Tom Your complaint is about questions you can't act on, presumably because you waste time clicking on the links only to find out you can't cast a vote. My response was that there's a solution to that problem if you just pay a little attention to what's presented to you on the page.

Comment: @TylerH Problem is that number of items in that page is limited. If you don't have 20K then you can easily find yourself in situation that almost all items are ones you cannot cast a vote on. It can be frustrating.

Answer (score 15):

My [Hide Roomba Bound Posts](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/tree/master/Hide-Roomba-Bound-Posts) userscript does exactly this:

[image]

Though I'd appreciate having an option to hide posts that will be roomba'd integrated into the site itself.

One disadvantage of the above script is that it runs on the client-side, so the number of questions that are displayed is not fixed. The shorter the time span viewed, the more questions that are listed will get roomba'd, and the fewer questions will be visible which require manual deletion.

Comment: Intresting, and I see another script there (https://stackapps.com/questions/7239/roomba-forecaster-when-will-the-question-be-roombaed-if-it-wont-why) for my last suggestion too

Comment: Does your script still work? I was using it until one of the SO updates broke it. It doesn't remove the roomba posts for me now.

Comment: @Dharman It's still working normally for me. Check that you're on the delete votes page, and that the script is active and enabled. If it is, can you open the browser console and see if there are any errors? Maybe a different userscript of yours is interfering with it, though that sounds unlikely

Comment: Thanks, you are right there was another script interfering.

Comment: @Dharman Is it a public one that others may have as well? If so, I'd like to fix the incompatibility (and I'm curious too), do you have a link?

Comment: Yeah, it's one of Sam's https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/10kToolsHelper.user.js

Comment: @CertainPerformance Perhaps you and Sam, and some of the other fine people who make these userscripts, might want to consider getting together and making a GitHub organisation to store said script? Then there would be a central place for people to get them, a central place to report bugs, etc.

Comment: @Dharman Fixed now, see https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/pull/90 and https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/commit/88b4b9025872044bb7a7aa4b091881919085e697

Comment: Is there any problem going on with "Stack Hide Roomba Bound Posts" user script? I am not able to make it work since few months now. Tried Enable/Disable, Uninstall/Install. The check box does not appear on Delete Vote page at all. Script is Active and Enabled on that page. There are no errors in browser console. Can you please suggest how can I make this work?