# Again, stop users from repeating their closed question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions, closed-questions, post-notice

I will repeat [myself again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396474/8620333)<sup>1</sup> as a feature request because it's very annoying to see that the effort we are doing is completely useless.

1. You close a question as duplicate
2. The user doesn't even bother to read or understand the *perfect* duplicate
3. They ask exactly the same question again and gets an answer! (unless I am able to catch them again)

Some examples to illustrate: [clone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64684006/8620333) ([original](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64682091/8620333)) | [clone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64655938/8620333) ([original](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64655802/8620333)) ... I can add even more.

What's the point of closing questions in this case? Why I don't simply answer them and enter the 1 Million Rep race?

---

If this is an intended behavior and there is nothing wrong with people repeating their questions then I would love to have a confirmation for this so I can stop my complaints. Something like:

> People are allowed to repeat their question again and again until they get the answer they want.  - SO Team

If not (and I suspect it's not) we should really do something.

### Well, what are the solutions?

<sup>I am not expecting to have *all* of them implemented but at least considered as ideas to have something implemented. Any other suggestion is also welcome.</sup>

The easiest one is to do a simple text check to detect the copy/paste. I think it's easy to identify that someone is copying more than 50% of their old question and prevent them from repeating the same question.

Block the user account from asking a new question for few hours if one of their questions is closed. I doubt that someone will ask two different questions within a few minutes. If a user is asking a new question after a closure then it's either the same question or closely related (the same issue but asked differently). Blocking the user will prevent the repetition and we can encourage them to edit their actual question.

Edit the banner to make it clear that you should **edit your question** and **never ever repeat it** (["How do I ask a good question" page needs explicit statement "Don't repost your questions"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400273/8620333))

> [image]

Make it easier for us to delete questions. If we cannot prevent such behavior, let's make the cleaning job easier so we can later delete the garbage (related: [Remove Roomba's questions from the delete tools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401817/8620333))

---

If this feature request will not be considered, it would be good to also get a reply like:

> Thanks for your effort, we appreciate those suggestions but unfortunately we won't do them. We already have a bunch of new features in the development queue and it's not in our priorities to make the process of asking questions difficult for new users. - SO Team

It's good to have a clear No or Yes so we are fixed.

<sup>1: since people are allowed to repeat the exact same question, why not doing the same? After all, I wrote it differently so it should be ok.</sup>

Comment: why isn't this [meta-tag:status-review]

Comment: @gnat +14 in 1h should be enough to have it added automatically I guess ;)

Comment: you need to make small steps, that nobody hardly notices, [to get things done](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394552/you-can-edit-the-question-or-post-a-new-one). This is way too drastic ....

Comment: So targeted drone strikes is off the table?

Comment: I half expected your last question on this subject to be closed. Would've made for some sweet sweet irony.

Comment: This needs to be implemented. Im going to bump this on purpose.

Comment: "Block the user account for few hours if one of his questions is closed" - rather, if they try to post a new question within say 4h of the original question being closed **and the new question is very similar to the previous**, immediately redirect them to the original question and put them in Edit mode.

Comment: @rene That particular small step doesn't do anything to fix the underlying issues that **cause** the posting of bad questions to begin with. Yes, the end result is positive overall, but Stack Overflow's most pressing problems cannot and will not be solved by small steps. We can put a thousand band-aids on SO's bullet wounds and they'll still be gushing blood.

Comment: @IanKemp All  true and agreed. Do notice the difference between mine and many other proposals: Mine got implemented ...

Comment: @rene And many other similarly simple proposals haven't, e.g. (1) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345318/the-ask-question-button-must-be-easily-accessible (2) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385519/include-dont-post-images-of-code-in-the-guide (3) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400273/how-do-i-ask-a-good-question-page-needs-explicit-statement-dont-repost-your. But please, continue to believe that you getting lucky is due to your FR being simple and easy.

Comment: @IanKemp he's not lucky, he's rene .. after all these years, he knows how to convince them ;)

Comment: Plenty of people join Stack Overflow to ask 1 question, and then never come back. I am suspicious of people who make a new account for every new (or duplicate) question.

Comment: You know what distinguishes a "Critic" from a "ranting disgruntled user"? Fact-checking...

Comment: [This may be of use](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355416/on-downvotes-or-more-precisely-why-people-downvote-things). A lot of this problem is down to people signing up for something that... isn't actually there.

Answer (score 35):

A couple of random thoughts on this

## A hard block won't prevent this

We already have a [question ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th). Doing this will get you there a *lot* faster and getting out of the ban isn't easy (nor can mods undo it). This is our main defense against repeated question asking. This isn't a new problem at all and the ban works really well.

Harder blocks just mean people start rolling up sock accounts to evade the ban. I found a whole university IP (probably a computer lab for students) where people are using junk email accounts to just chain roll-up accounts and repeatedly ask the same homework question over and over until someone answers before it gets closed. I don't see blocks solving this.

## Close dialogues are confusing new users

[image: Post a new question]

Do you see the problem? (emphasis mine)

> You can edit the question or **post a new one**

I've warned more users than I care to count about question repetition and one responded with (my paraphrase since I can't find the original)

> But the system told me to post a new question, so I did

Fix this verbiage. It's low-hanging fruit and it would help new users by not directing them to do something they shouldn't.

Comment: But question ban consider *poorly-received* questions and you need to post *many* of them. If you post a good question that get closed and right after you post the same that get an answer, I don't think the system will consider this as a bad behavior and will ban the user.

Comment: *"But the system told me to post a new question, so I did"* FWIW, I've frequently comments in that vein on Physics.SE, which has a rather strict policy regarding homework-like questions (and a constant stream of "homework dumpers" who are oblivious to that policy). At the very least, we need to let the OP know that a "new question" has to actually *be* new, and has to address the issues mentioned in the close notice (& comments), not a carbon copy or minor re-wording of the closed question.

Comment: This has been a long standing problem.  The text must be changed so that it does not say "post a new one".  It's ridiculous that this has still not been fixed.

Comment: Just hooooow hard can it be? Just delete the text in a paragraph, something even a noob like me can do with HTML. Will this [take 5 years again?!?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402600/12708583).

Comment: is there any chance that this feature get consireded? Moderators cannot do some pressure? I am really *pissed off* with all the questions that get repeated after getting closed.

Comment: @TemaniAfif We don't have any more ability than you to change priorities. But a significant number of folks just continue to roll up new accounts, which is a harder problem to tamp down. I still stand by my answer: this would just push people to make more junk accounts, which means more mod work

Comment: Well, I don't expect them to implement the ban or any complex feature I listed but at least to change the banner content and remove that *ask a new question* .. at least this one which is so easy.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the intent of the "post a new one" prompt is to signal that it is permissible to *start over* and ask an actually *new* question about the same problem. Perhaps explicitly using the words "start over" would help?

Answer (score -52):

I don't see any substantial problem to solve here. Both those clones have been deleted.

You've already spent more time here (and that of other people) than it probably *actually* costs you to just cast a duplicate vote on the duplicate, and/or move on with your day.

Pick your battles.

Comment: *Both those clones have been deleted.* --> those are 2 cases among many I face regularly. I am not trying to fix particular cases. I want to fix the core problem

Comment: There is no core problem. The site is not awash with this. You're just wasting your time...

Comment: *The site is not awash with this* --> it is. I won't raise a meta question for 1 case among 1000. Even if we consider it's not, this is a good reason to do something now before getting awash with this. If such behavior become the rule instead of being the exception then we can do nothing

Comment: It really isn't, but okay - good luck!

Comment: I see it done nearly daily. [Just yesterday, in fact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64722847/)... SO telling people to repost their closed questions essentially verbatim is horrible guidance for both the asker on the receiving end of the closure as well as curators and tag watchers that have to (futilely, as shown in the question here) explain that it's just going to be closed again if it's off-topic.

Comment: Not so much the point, this is patching a potential issue as opposed to modifying behavior to help solve it.

Comment: I agree with @AlexanderBunting, because it just litters SO with duplicates we don't ant.

Comment: I can see why you would downvote this answer. I'm not sure I understand why it needs to be deleted. Will the final delete voter be so kind to share their thoughts in a comment before they hit delete? I'm eager to learn a thing or two.

Comment: @rene I don't know, but maybe the answerer deleted it themselves? Never mind, it was delete voted, and that shouldn't happen, because it's called censoring.

Comment: This absolutely is a problem and it’s not just limited to Stack Overflow.  I see examples of users submitting the same question almost daily.  The problem also exists with answers, users will resubmit the same answer, and I quote “I thought the moderator made a mistake” as the justification for submitting a terrible answer multiple times.