# Is Stack Overflow now encouraging users to ask a new question instead of re-editing the marked duplicated question for a reopen?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question ([Find missing dates of each product where multiple products are stored in the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66886368/find-missing-dates-of-each-product-where-multiple-products-are-stored-in-the-sam)) yesterday and was marked duplicated. I checked the solution of the duplicated question today and found that doesn't solve my problem. So as always, I re-edited my question title and body and waited for a reopen.

But somehow I noticed that the phrases of the hint seem to change, if I remember correctly.

Now it's stated as:

> Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this
> question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one.

Has that really changed? Is it encouraging users/me to ask a new question instead of re-editing and waiting for a reopen now?

I am not going to judge which approach is better. I am just being curious whether SO has really changed their guideline towards that. I would adjust my behaviour to match the new guideline, which is deleting the duplicated and go ask a new one.

Comment: Good. The duplicated question resolve my question and I know what I should do now. Just delete the old, re-edit the old and ask a new one.  Ok cool. SO did make a change on this.

Comment: DO NOT ASK NEW QUESTION. Edit the old one to make it on topic or add details to explain why it is not duplicate. Banner is confusing and is not telling properly what they should do.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar But the answers in the duplicated one suggest asking a new one, just not the old one. It takes years for a reopen after re-editing the old question.

Comment: You didn't read carefully. If you are basically asking about same problem, then you should edit the old one. If you really have totally new unrelated problem, then ask new one.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Ah I see. I skipped the big `NO` at the very beginning of that answer. But the question is that it takes ages for a reopen and whether the reopen question has the same rank in the site is another considerable topic. So why don't I just delete the old one and ask a new one which **have been re-edited carefully**?

Comment: Because that is the easiest way to get into the question ban. Those closed and deleted questions will count. You got lucky so far, but don't repeat this in the future.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Ok I get this. I will follow your advice. Is there any way can make reopen faster by the way?

Comment: No, you cannot make it faster. If it does not get reopened after a while, you can always aske here, but this can also have negative effect if your question is really not good enough for reopening. You have enough reputation to review questions in Reopen vote queue, and the less questions are there the faster is the process.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Ok I see. Thank for for all the extra info. Really appreciated. ;P

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402656/again-stop-users-from-repeating-their-closed-question